# How to allow text,space and dot only in android

Tags: java, android

Im creating simple application in andriod.. I want to allow only alphabets,space and dot only in edittext. I wrote some code but not working.

Here my code:

```js
name.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {
                new InputFilter() {
                    @Override
                    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence cs, int start,
                                               int end, Spanned spanned, int dStart, int dEnd) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        if(cs.equals("")){ // for backspace
                            return cs;
                        }
                        if(cs.toString().matches("[a-zA-Z. ]")){
                            return cs;
                        }
                        return "";
                    }
                }
        });
```

Please anyone help..

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: `android:digits = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ. "` Add this to your `XML` `editText`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `*` to your regex.

Try this regex :

```
       cs.toString().matches("^[a-zA-Z. ]*$")
```

As you did not specify `*` in your regular expression, it tries to match only one character.

**Update:**

You can further simplify your code and change

```
    if(cs.equals("")){ // for backspace
           return cs;
     }
     if(cs.toString().matches("[a-zA-Z. ]*")){
         return cs;
     }
     return cs;
```

to

```
    if(cs.toString().matches("[a-zA-Z. ]+")){
         return cs;
     }
     return "";
```

The difference is now you are using `+` instead of `*`.

```
     * matched 0 or more occurrences
     + matched 1 or more occurrences
```

So there is no need to explicitly check for `empty string`.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your code in if condition with below code

```
if(cs.toString().matches("[a-zA-Z. ]*")){
    return cs; 
}
```